# Почему подвал не опускается вниз?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Подвал при заполнении блока не опускается вниз, а стоит на месте. Как это решить? И главное, отчего это возникло, в чем ошибка?

```css
    *** {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
    }
    html {
     height: 100%;
    }
    body {
     font: 12px/18px Arial, Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
     height: 100%;
    }
    a {
     color: blue;
     outline: none;
     text-decoration: underline;
    }
    a:hover {
     text-decoration: none;
    }
    p {
     margin: 0 0 18px
    }
    img {
     border: none;
    }
    input {
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    #wrapper {
     width: 100%;
     min-width: 1000px;
     min-height: 100%;
     height: auto !important;
     height: 100%;
    }
    
    /* Header
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #header {
        position: relative;
        height: 74px;
        background: #000000 ;
    }
    #middle {
     width: 100%;
     padding:0 0 0 0px;
     height: 1%;
     position: relative;
    }
    #middle:after {
     content: '.';
     display: block;
     clear: both;
     visibility: hidden;
     height: 0;
    }
    #container {
     width: 100%;
     float: left;
     overflow: hidden;
    
    }
    #content {
     padding: 20px 420px 50px 10px;
    }
    
    /* Sidebar Right
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #sideRight {
     float: left;
     margin-right: -3px;
     width: 400px;
     margin-left: -400px;
     position: relative;
    }
    
    
    /* Footer
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #footer {
        height:45px;
        width:100%;
        position:absolute;
        bottom:0;
        background: #CC0000;
    }
    
    /* блок
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #rounded {
     border: 1px solid #000000;
     background-color: #FfF;
     border-radius: 30px;
     -moz-border-radius: 30px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
     padding:10px ;
    }

    #otstup {
     padding:50px
    }
```

```html
    <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header"></div><!-- #header-->
     <div id="middle">
      <div id="container">
       <div id="content">
        <div id="otstup">
                        <div id="rounded">
                <left><strong>Content:</strong> Lorem...<br>Sed...
                            </left>
               </div>
                    </div>
       </div><!--#rounded-->
      </div><!-- #container-->
      <div class="sidebar" id="sideRight">
            <div id="otstup">
          <div id="rounded">Integer...</div>
            </div>
            <div id="otstup">
                <div id="rounded">Vestibulum...</div>
            </div>
     </div><!-- #middle-->
    </div><!-- #wrapper -->
    
    <div id="footer">
     <center><strong>Footer:</strong> </center>
    </div><!-- #footer -->
```

Comment: Дайтепо, пожалуйста, ссылку на сайт.

Comment: Он локальный.

Comment: Можно выложить на DropBox.

Comment: Пытался собрать из исходников Dropbox - не получается.

Comment: Я имел в виду вот этот -> dropbox.com - файловое хранилище.

Comment: см. тут: shublog.ru/html-and-css/kak-prizhimat-podval-k-nizhnejj-chasti-brauzera/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При позиционировании как absolute bottom указывает на координату относительно низа видимой области в браузере. И зависит оно только от размеров её, а от содержимого как-то никак.

Чтобы положение блока рассчитывалось относительно размеров и положения родительского блока, надо использовать position: relative.

Но, ввиду того, что в исходном коде указана высота блока информации (middle) в 1%, положение рассчитается неверно и блок переместится вверх. Если же положиться на математические способности браузера и убрать эту смущающую строчку, всё будет в порядке =)

Comment: Вот посмотрите http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23843821/temp/index.html

Comment: Если её нужно переместить в самый низ, то уберите position:absolute (чтобы был относительный режим) и уберите у блока middle непонятное свойство height: 1%. (зачем?)
Блок переедет в самый низ.